# IF Statement argument update and function recall

Tags: c, if-statement, for-loop, embedded

Instead of copying code, I would like to call to another function.

There are two functions, the one function, GetSlaves() returns with a number of slaves found during a scan.

Thing is, I suspect sometimes the returned value is incorrect, while a slave is down or stuck. Therefore I would like to run the GetSlaves function again if I am not happy with the number of slaves found. Please see the code below, questions follow.

```
SetSlaves(slaves)
{

  if (slaves<3 || slaves>6) // I expect 4 or 6 to be found
  {
    for (tmp2 = 0; tmp2<3; tmp2++) // Try 3 times
    {
        GetSlaves(); // This function will scan for new slaves and then call SetSlaves(slaves);
    }
  }
  else 
  {
      WriteFlash(VMSSlaves,slaves); // I am happy with what was found, Sets the number of slaves found
  }

}
```

My Question is, when the primary function is called again from the For statement, will it update the *slaves* variable (for instance a 4 is returned) and exit the IF and thus also the FOR..

Or, will the loop be endless if a slave is down and the two functions will call each other endlessly?

Comment: In answer to my own question, I realize now that if a slave is down the loop will be endless due to the two functions calling each other. Need more coffee!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some serious control problems here and it may loop forever: when SetSlaves is called with a number of slaves, and the number is not to your liking, GetSlaves is called, which calls SetSlaves. Even if the number is to your liking, it will return, only to be in the loop of tmp2, calling GetSlaves which calls SetSlaves again. If now the number is not to your liking, the whole process repeats and can repeat indefinitly. And note that this is an indirect form of recursion.

My advice would be to have GetSlaves return the number of slaves and that the caller decides whether to call SetSlaves, and not have GetSlaves call SetSlaves.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct. The loop would be endless if the if condition is satisfied and it enters the for loop.
In my opinion, the structure of the code is a bit iffy. I would rather have getslaves just get me number of slaves, and not call setslaves.